# cURL request freeze the browser

Tags: php, curl, freeze, php-curl

I try to request an URL width cURL, but there is no answer and the option CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT doesn't work.

I have no answer at all... I suppose that the server doesn't answer. I try to use the Chrome plugin called Restlet Client - REST API Testing to test the URL, but no answer too.

```php
    private function curlInterrogation(){
            try {       
                $ch = curl_init();
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, WS_L2_URL.$this->code);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, TRUE);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, WS_USER . ':' . WS_PASS);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, false );
                $result = curl_exec($ch);
                curl_close($ch);
                return $result;
            } catch (Exception $ex) {
                Noyau::setError('Curl error #%d: %s', $e->getCode(), $e->getMessage() );
                return array();
            }
        }
```

Each time i run my function, i freeze my browser for the domain (i can browse in other website) and i have to restart my browser.

With the CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT option, should the execution stop and return that it can not connect to server ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Are you sure the curl_exec is where the execution is freezing? If the returned data are too big it can take time processing them and it can freeze the chrome plugin too.

Comment: Why don't you try to use Postman app instead of Advanced Rest Client from Chrome? It is a better tool to see what is happening with your request and it won't freeze if the response takes too long to arrive.

Comment: Yes i'm sure, that the curl_exec is where the execution is freezing. When i comment it, there is no freeze...

Comment: I have to inform too, that when the server give an answer everything works like a charm. My problem is only when the server does not answer...

Comment: @Fabiano i try with postam as you said. It's the same problem no answer from the server and the timeout don't work...

Comment: I found this useful for the same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828559/how-can-i-figure-out-why-curl-is-hanging-and-unresponsive

Answer (score 0):

Try to check [cURL Php Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) if you're trying to check cURL info.

Nonetheless, just check [Php cURL Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php).

Then going to your code (Check my comments):

```
private function curlInterrogation(){
            try {       
                $ch = curl_init();
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, WS_L2_URL.$this->code);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, TRUE);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, WS_USER . ':' . WS_PASS);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, false );
                $result = curl_exec($ch);
                curl_close($ch); //You've just closed the execution early before return
                return $result; //Returning just the execution is most likely an empty page
            } catch (Exception $ex) {
                Noyau::setError('Curl error #%d: %s', $e->getCode(), $e->getMessage() );
                return array();
            }
        }
```

Try this

```
function TestCurl(){ //Just function

        try{
            $base_url = 'https://www.example.com'; //Replace this with your client URL
            $user_name = 'user'; //Replace with username
            $user_pass = 'pass'; //Replace with password
            $ch = curl_init(); //Initializes a new session and return a cURL handle

            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $base_url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, TRUE);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $user_name.":".$user_pass);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, false );

            curl_exec($ch);

            $info = curl_getinfo($ch);

            echo 'Took ', $info['total_time'], ' seconds to send a request to ', $info['url'], "\n";

            curl_close($ch); // <- Always put this at the end of the execution
        } 
        catch (Exception $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    //Call TestCurl function
    TestCurl();
```

Comment: I don't understand your recommandation. In the cURL Php Manual, there are several examples with a return after curl_close(). And how could i manage data like an array receveid from curl if not ?

Comment: Like i said in the other comment : when the server give an answer everything works like a charm. My problem is only when the server does not answer...